# Does this flashback scene refer to an actual previous episode?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

In the Television series, [**How I met Your Mother**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460649/), [Season 8 Episode 11](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2556002/), a reference has been made to a point of time 5 years ago where Barney doesn't follows the rule of a "Jinx" and ends up in a hospital.

My question is, does this refers to an actual episode in some previous season of the television show? Because I think that I remember Barney in Hospital.

Comment: '5 _years_ ago' can be interpreted as '5 _seasons_ ago'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That flashback was from the **Season 3 finale** [***Miracles***](http://how-i-met-your-mother.wikia.com/wiki/Miracles):

> Barney was crossing the street to the get to the hospital when he is hit by a bus driving the wrong way down a one way street.
>
> [image: HIMYM] <sup>[[Source](http://www.prosieben.at/tv/how-i-met-your-mother/episoden/staffel-3/wunder-ueber-oewunder-folge-20-staffel3-1.3206319/)]</sup>

Comment: Why Barney get to the hospital? Because Ted had a [car accident in a taxi](http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101105020340/himym/images/e/e1/Ted_pre_smash.png).

Comment: @SonerGönül - Yes, I provided a link so people can read more about the episode if they are interested.

Comment: Was there a mention of "Ginx" in the episode?

Comment: @user221287 - No, the scene where they basically explain their 'Jinx' game was not in the _Miracle_ episode. You can see that Lily is wearing a wig so her hair looks like in that episode, but with Marshall they didn't bother. His hair is noticably shorter.